# STM32G431 CMSIS clock setup failed

Tags: stm32, clock

I am currently developing with the WeAct Studio STM32G431 Board, but when I tried to configure the clock setup something went terribly wrong. During the debugging process the ST link connection broke down and afterwards I could never reach the chip again. But the previous program still runs fine and with the previous clock frequency, so nothing changed.
Where is the bug in my clock config code that stopped SWD functionality from working?

This is the board:(G431) (although it's from China, it's of a high quality)
https://github.com/WeActStudio/WeActStudio.STM32G431CoreBoard

This is the code:

```c
void clockConfig() {

    /*************>>>>>>>     STEPS       <<<<<<<<************

    1. ENABLE HSE and wait for the HSE to become Ready
    2. Set the POWER ENABLE CLOCK and VOLTAGE REGULATOR
    3. Configure the FLASH PREFETCH and the LATENCY Related Settings
    4. Configure the PRESCALARS HCLK, PCLK1, PCLK2
    5. Configure the MAIN PLL
    6. Enable the PLL and wait for it to become ready
    7. Select the Clock Source and wait for it to be set

    ********************************************************/

    // enable HSE
    RCC->CR |= 1<<16;
    while (!(RCC->CR & (1<<17)));


    // set power enable clock and voltage regulator
    RCC->APB1ENR1 |= (1<<28);   // PWR EN
    PWR->CR1 |= (1<<9);         // voltage scale


    // configure flash prefetch and latency related settings
    FLASH->ACR = (1<<2) | (1<<9) | (1<<10);


    // configure PSC
    // AHB PSC
    RCC->CFGR &= ~(1<<4);

    // APB1 PSC
    RCC->CFGR &= ~(7<<8);

    // APB2 PSC
    RCC->CFGR &= ~(7<<11);


    // configure main PLL
    RCC->PLLCFGR |= (2 <<4);    // PLL M
    RCC->PLLCFGR |= (85<<8);    // PLL N
    RCC->PLLCFGR &= ~(3<<25);   // PLL R
    RCC->PLLCFGR |= (1<<24);    // PLL R EN
    RCC->PLLCFGR |= (0b11<<0);  // PLL SRC


    // enable PLL
    RCC->CR |= (1<<24);
    while (!(RCC->CR & (1<<25)));

    // select clock sources
    RCC->CFGR |= (0xF<<0);
    while (!(RCC->CFGR & (3<<2)));

}

int main(void)
{

    init();
    clockConfig();

    while (1)
    {

        // code

    }

    loop:
        goto loop;
}
```

Comment: So is that the code that works or the code that does not work? What was the change between working and non-working code? Where did this code come from and how do you know it is even supposed to work?

Comment: I guess you are aware that you can press the BOOT0 button when powering the device to prevent it from running the problematic firmware. Then you should be able to connect to it again. Connect under reset is also possible if your upload software supports it.

Comment: @Justme The previous code was just a gpio initalisation and blinking Port E3 with a simple while loop delay. It's pretty irrelevant.

The onlything I changed was that I added the clockConfig() function then after uploading the connection got lost.

I followed the instructions from the following page and changed it according to the reference manual. I got the values from a cubeMX configuration for the same board.
https://controllerstech.com/stm32-clock-setup-using-registers/

Comment: @JakobFlocke The instructions are made for another STM32 model, F446. Why are you trying to run code intended for F446 on a G431?

Comment: @justme That the only resource I found and I tweaked it according to the reference manual. I cant learn stuff from thin air.

Answer (score 0):

The code is intended for another MCU model. It may not work on another MCU model if the RCC peripheral is different.

You are also reading the register default value and ORing your values on top of it. So you are not setting the values to what you want to set them.